# 0 byte files when downloading from ftp

Tags: java, ftp, apache-commons

Hi I'm writing a program that needs to download some files from an ftp using apache commons, however when I try to download, the program creates a zero byte file and moves on to the next file. Here is my code:

```
 String FTPPath = link.attr("href");

                    URL url = new URL(FTPPath);

                    String host = url.getHost();

                    FTPClient client = new FTPClient();



                        client.connect(host);
                        client.login("anonymous", "anonymous");

                        boolean success = client.changeWorkingDirectory(url.getPath());

                        FTPFile[] list = client.listFiles();

                       // boolean success = client.changeWorkingDirectory(url.getPath());
                        for (FTPFile f : list) {

                            String fileName = f.getName();

                            if(fileName.endsWith(".raw")){
                                System.out.println(fileName + " Downloading");

                                //client.download(fileName, new java.io.File(fileName));
                                String remoteFile1 = f.getLink();


                                File downloadFile1 = new File(fileName);
                                OutputStream outputStream1 = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(downloadFile1));
                                success = client.retrieveFile(remoteFile1, outputStream1);
                                outputStream1.close();

                                if (success) {
                                    System.out.println(fileName +" has been downloaded successfully.");
                                }

                            }


                        }


                }
```

It the success variable is apparently staying at false. but I'm not getting any other error message.

Here is an example of the one of the ftps I'm trying to download from.

ftp://ftp.pride.ebi.ac.uk/pride/data/archive/2015/11/PXD000918

Comment: Don't call f.getLink() unless the file is a symbolic link.  From the javadoc: If the FTPFile is a symbolic link, this method returns the name of the file being pointed to by the symbolic link. Otherwise it returns null.

Comment: What should I use instead then to download the file?

Comment: Thank you I edited the line to  String remoteFile1 = f.getName(); and it worked.